# [Symfony 4][LiipImagine] Using liipImagine in a controller

Tags: dependency-injection, controller, symfony4, liipimaginebundle

(before asking for help, i prefer to tell you my english sucks a lot really sorry in advance... And i'm a real beginner in php and symfony so that's why i'm here..)

**My problem :**

I try to use LiipImagine for a website with a photo gallery, because i need to create somes thumbnails when i upload photos, and i see in documentation that i can use LiipImagine in my controller with my upload method, so, before anything else, i try to copy paste the code in documentation, not work, try to find on internet but i always get the error **"Service "liip_imagine.cache.mnagaer" not found"**

I understand that i need to inject LiipImagine in my controller but i'm a bit confused, i don't know how to do it properly, and i don't know to how to properly use my filter after that..

My uploading method is :

```
/**
 * @Route("/new", name="photo_new", methods={"GET","POST"})
 */
public function new(CategorieRepository  $cat, Request $request): Response
{
    $photo = new Photo();
    $form = $this->createForm(PhotoType::class, $photo);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        // Je récupère les informations du fichier uploadé
        $photoUploade = $form->get("nom_photo")->getData();

        // Je récupère le nom du fichier uploadé
        $nomPhoto = pathinfo($photoUploade->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);

        // Je remplace les espaces dans le nom du fichier
        $nomPhoto = str_replace(" ", "_", $nomPhoto);

        // Je rajoute un string unique (pour éviter les fichiers doublons) et l'extension du fichier téléchargé
        $nomPhoto .= uniqid() . "." . $photoUploade->guessExtension();

        // J'enregistre le fichier uploadé sur mon serveur, dans le dossier public/images
        $photoUploade->move("images", $nomPhoto);

        // Pour enregistrer l'information en BDD
        $photo->setnomPhoto($nomPhoto);
        $entityManager->persist($photo);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('photo_index');
    }
```

If someone could help me to understand it i would really appreciate..

Answer (score 0):

got it..

Need this class

```
use Liip\ImagineBundle\Service\FilterService;
```

Then inject it in the method and then

```
$minPhoto = $FilterService->getUrlOfFilteredImage("images/".$nomPhoto, 'mini');
```

it make my thumbnail with my "mini" filter